# Lucene.NET faceted search

Tags: lucene.net, faceted-search

I found a great tutorial on performing a faceted search.

http://www.devatwork.nl/articles/lucenenet/faceted-search-and-drill-down-lucenenet/

This article does not explain how to retrieve the narrowed available attributes to filter from (for further drill down).

Lets say I am looking for planners that are red. When I perform the faceted search, I want to return all available attributes to filter from that are red. Then when I add a "weekly format" filter, I want the attribute list to get even smaller, containing only filters available for the segmented group.

I want love to use Solr/SolrNET but I am in a shared hosting situation with limited access to the actual server.

I am fairly new to lucene.net, so examples are much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, you get a BitArray containing the list of the filtered results. In the tutorial's example, you will have combinedResults as this list. If you want to further narrow this down, you need to reiterate the process: run another searchQuery and intersect the results with the BitArray you have for combinedResults.

Answer (score 0):

> I want love to use Solr/SolrNET but I am in a shared hosting situation with limited access to the actual server.

You can always use an off-site, hosted Solr solution. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2168634/how-to-evaluate-hosted-full-text-search-solutions) for more information.