# What search tools are available for ASP.NET site?

Tags: asp.net, faceted-search

Is there any good search tools for asp.net I can buy to carry out search indexes easily on data I have in my database?

What I require is something that would carry out a general site search of articles but also faceted search as well. Faceted search is quite important feature.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with Mauricio Scheffer, using Solr.NET will help achieve what you want. I implemented a basic ASP.NET web form example around a year back. I found this link to be very useful to get me started: http://crazorsharp.blogspot.co.uk/2010/01/full-text-search-using-solr-lucene-and.html

Using the example (above), I managed to create this (DISCLAIMER: personal site): http://surinder.computing-studio.com/post/2011/01/14/At-Last!-Created-My-Own-eBay-Style-Search-Using-Solrnet.aspx

Answer (score 4):

You can implement facets with [Lucene.NET](http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/), [Solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/), [Sphinx](http://sphinxsearch.com/), [FAST](http://sharepoint.microsoft.com/en-us/product/capabilities/search/Pages/Search-Server.aspx), [Endeca](http://www.endeca.com/en/solutions/by-technology/enterprise-search.html), probably also [Xapian](http://xapian.org/).

None of these will be trivial to integrate though, since they use very different data structures from relational databases. Usually you have to denormalize your data to feed it to a full-text search engine.

[SolrNet](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/) includes a [sample ASP.NET MVC application](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/SampleApp) that shows how to implement [facets](http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/wiki/Facets) with Solr.

Disclaimer: I'm the author of SolrNet.

Comment: Thanks I shall take a look.

I have used Lucene.NET to index my whole database to carry out a keyword search. But I didn't exactly know how to create facets using Lucene. Is SolrNet similar to Lucene where the whole database has to be indexed? My database is going to be very large.

Comment: @R100: about facets with lucene.net, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2939019/lucene-net-faceted-search

Comment: @R100: actually you don't have to index the whole database with Lucene or Solr, just the part you want to search.

Comment: @R100: also, Solr can be easily distributed in case the index gets too large: http://wiki.apache.org/solr/DistributedSearch

Comment: Thanks for your help Mauricio. My search will needs to display different facets depending on a report type. Each report type could have different information. What would be the best way to implement this? Would I create a seperate index for each report type and then search that index for my facet? Any further help would be appreciated.

Comment: @R100: there is no straight answer to that, it depends. However it depends more on *what* you're searching than the facets you're showing.

Answer (score 1):

Lucene .net great http://incubator.apache.org/lucene.net/

Its a .net port of the very popular Java search library Lucene.

Now, I prefer having a stand along search engine to remove the strain from my site. I use Solr which is Java, but you can use SolrSharp http://solrsharp.codeplex.com/ or SolrNet  http://code.google.com/p/solrnet/ to intergrate with solr.